# C++ lambda & std::function capture by value memory management?

Tags: c++, memory-management, lambda, new-operator

Where do lambdas and std::functions store variables captured by value?

```
int i = 1;
auto l = [i](void) mutable { return i++; };
std::function<int(void)> f = l;
```

Do they call the new operator? If I provide my own new operator, will it be used by lambdas?

Comment: Lambdas are classes that save variables as member data and `std::function` just saves the lambda. Depending on the size of the callable object it either fits inside the `std::function` or sits on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

From [expr.prim.lambda] 5.1.2(15)

> An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is = or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that is not of the form & identifier or & identifier initializer. **For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type**. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. The type of such a data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity if the entity is not a reference to an object, or the referenced type otherwise. [ Note: If the
>   captured entity is a reference to a function, the corresponding data member is also a reference to a function. —end note ] A member of an anonymous union shall not be captured by copy.

<sup>emphasis mine</sup>

So a variable captured by value will be stored as member of the closure type.  The closure type is unspecified as per 5.1.2(3)

> The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type — called the closure type — whose properties are described below. This class type is neither an aggregate (8.5.1) nor a literal type (3.9). The closure type is declared in the smallest block scope, class scope, or namespace scope that contains the corresponding lambda-expression.

Answer (score 0):

At compile time lambdas are actually turned into classes. So if you had the following.

```
int a; Widget widget; 

auto somelambda = [=a,&widget](){

}
```

You could actually think of it as

```
class SomeLambda
{
int a;
Widge& w;
...
}
```

Which should make you really cautious because you can have dangling references.